# Partial classes- Member with same name already exist errors

Tags: asp.net, webforms, partial-classes, vs-web-application-project

I am trying to change a website to a web application but seems to get lot of issues as some of the subroutines are in both partial classes spread across different files.
Just wondering why it didn't generate any issues in Website where as in web application it is throwing errors like "Member with same name or signature is already declared in the class"

Comment: "I am trying to change a website to a web application" - uhhh, dare I ask, are you working with a project dating back to Visual Studio 2005?

Comment: "Just wondering why it didn't generate any issues in Website"  - those issues were always there, but "Website projects" (of the aformentioned VS2005-variety... which need to _die_) don't have any kind of build-system, true compilation, etc - so you'd get the same errors but at runtime instead of design-time - *or* you've somehow messed up your `App_Code` folder...

Comment: Sounds like something was copied twice.

Comment: @Dai  Yes it is a very old project, web forms & vb.net. This application is already in production  & don't have any issues. All i am trying to do is create a web application out of that & i am noticing lot of duplicate code in partial classes.  I recently started looking at this codebase & wondering why it didn't fail until now. Even codebehind for MasterPage is partial class & is creating issues there after converting to web application